# Is Senior Developer an acceptable title for business cards?

Tags: title

I work for a small company and we punch far above our weight. I have been lead developer on some of our flagship applications (>75,000 loc size). My manager has asked me to come up with five titles appropriate for business cards.

Is Senior Developer an appropriate title for business cards?

Comment: Titles are defined differently across cultures, industries and companies. Sometimes departments of the same company even interpret them differently. All that is to say that what's appropriate is entirely dependent on the situation and we aren't any more qualified than you are to make that decision. Consider asking for advice in chat instead.

Comment: It would mostly depend on the image you and your company are aiming for, generally it would probably be fine, it isn't really an out-of-the-box title i.e. Code Wizard Extraordinaire (although some companies may aim for this sort of humor and approachability). @Lilienthal is right, we cannot say any better than you in this situation unfortunately

Comment: You can put whatever your company wants on business cards. Senior developer sounds OK to me

Comment: Why must you come up with five titles?

Answer (score -2):

Look at some of the titles in the industry. You can probably get it from wikipedia.
I will list some of them just for reference:

- Associate
- Junior Analyst
- Manager
- Vice President
- Senior Analyst
- Director
- Team Lead
- Principal Architect
- Delivery Manager
- Support Analyst
- etc.